# GCM Notification is not working sometimes in Playframework(Play Java)

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging, playframework-2.3

I am writing code for GCM notification to send to my android app using the registered id with GCM Server and project API key. Sometimes it's not sending any notification and it's only working for some API keys, but not for others.

I am posting sample code here. I have searched the internet but I got only play Scala. But I need for play Java. I am using playframework with Java.

Is there any alternative code in Playframework?

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.Date;    
import java.util.List;    
import play.Logger;    
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;    
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;    
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;    
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

public class GcmNotification {

    public static boolean sendNotification(String notification, String regId) {
        // api key
        final Sender sender = new Sender("AIzaSyCQAE7VyFHreppcOkv7aXGk8JOxy4Osxdgvx");
        Result result = null;

        final Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
                .delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData("date", new Date().getTime() + "")
                .addData("message", notification).build();

        final List<String> regids = new ArrayList<String>();
        regids.add(regId);
        Logger.info("entered2 : " + regids.size());
        try {
            result = sender.send(message, regids, 1);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add the response from the GCM server when the messages are not received by the client application?

Comment: https://github.com/ykartal/GCMNotifier I hope this url helps you